# Web API(MVC) to keep running when Browser Window close

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I want Web API(MVC) to keep running even when i close my Browser Window.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by keep running? WebAPI will keep running till server process is running, it is not dependent on the browser.

Comment: I want MVC "View" to run in background when browser window closed.

Comment: @Tripti View will be visible only in browser how can it run in background?

Comment: Please update the question it seems that you are asking for Web API

Comment: @Tripti Tell what are you trying to implement.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this question is talking about Visual Studio's IIS Express starting and stopping being linked to the Browser.  By default, there is a setting for "Stop debugger when browser window is closed."  If you're just running a pure Web API and don't need a browser, then when you debug, you typically close the browser because it's an unnecessary page.  If that's the case, just check that setting and turn it off.

Answer (score -2):

Web API is running in local server or in case hosted then in IIS. it will close only when iis is stopped or the application hosted in it is stopped. So no need to worry. Read [this](https://www.asp.net/web-api) for more details

Comment: Although the question is vague, this does not answer the question.